# set axis limits in loglog plot with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do I create space around the points I've plotted with matplotlib?

For example, in this plot, the bottom left point is cutoff by the axis, but I would like a little more space between the point and the axis.
[image: example plot]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [2**i for i in xrange(4,14)]
y = [i**2 for i in x]
plt.loglog(x,y,'ro',basex=2,basey=2)
plt.xlim([0, 2**14]) # <--- this line does nothing
plt.show()
```

In interactive mode, the `xlim` line returns `(16.0, 16384)`, the old values instead of the new values I'm trying to set.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Zero can not be plotted on a loglog graph (log(0) = -inf).  It is silently failing because it can not use 0 as a limit.

Try `plt.xlim([1,2**14])` instead.

Comment: Silently failing wasn't helpful, but of course 0 can't be plotted! Good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here I use `plt.axis()` to set xmin and xmax values (similar to your `plt.xlim` call); but I use a variable 'buffer' built on the range and an interval. The range of the axis is derived from using the min and max values. Since log scale doesn't plot 0 or negatives, I set the `xmin` argument equal to 1 inside of the `.axis()` function call.

```
interval = 10

plot_range_buffer = (data.column.max() - data.column.min() / interval

plt.axis(
    xmin=1, # to keep scale if minimum is 0 or close to 0
    #xmin = data.column.min()-plot_range_buffer # subtracts interval buffer from min value
    xmax=data.column.max()+plot_range_buffer # adds the interval buffer to max value
)
```

We can do the same with the y-axis as needed. It's a lot of code to control one aspect of the plot, but I like using it within a user function if matplotlib.pyplot is being ornery.
Here's a two template user routines for trial and error. I tested the first one and it worked fine; I just built the second one as an alternative option but didn't test it...if it gives errors please let me know.

**User Function #1:** Total Control within Function

```
def plotcolumn(some_row_entry):
    """Selects data for some row entry
       Creates a scatter plot from two column variables
       Allows for user control over buffers through manipulation
           of interval that is relative to axis max,min range"""

    # numpy fancy selector for input argument
    data = data[data.some_row_entry == some_row_entry]

    # establish plot
    data.plot.scatter(
        'first_column',
        'second_column',
        logx=True,                                   # turn log xaxis on/off
        #logy=True                                    # turn log yaxis on/off
    )

    # axis range controls
    x_interval = 10
    y_interval = 10

    # x axis (ie x-axis variable)
    x_buffer = (data.first_column.max() - data.first_column.min()) / x_interval

    # y axis (ie y-axis variable)
    y_buffer = (data.second_column.max() - data.second_column.min()) / y_interval

    plt.axis(
        xmin=1,                                      # use for xaxis lower buffer if logx and close to 0
        xmax=data.first_column.max()+x_buffer,       # sets xaxis upper buffer
        #xmin=data.first_column.min()-x_buffer,      # sets xaxis lower buffer if not logx close to 0

        #ymin= 1,                                     # use for yaxis lower buffer if logy and close to 0
        ymax= data.second_column.max()+y_buffer,     # sets yaxis upper buffer
        ymin= data.second_column.min()-y_buffer     # sets yaxis lower if not logy close to 0
    )
```

**User Function #2:** Pass Arguments for One Axis & Interval

```
def plotcolumn_log_cond(some_row_entry, logaxis = 'x', interval = 10):

    """Selects data for some row entry
       Creates a scatter plot from two column variables.
       Arguments:
           Set axis to be logged (x or y as string)
           Pass interval value (as number)
       """


    # numpy fancy selector for input argument
    data = data[data.some_row_entry == some_row_entry]

    # establish plot
    data.plot.scatter(
        'first_column',
        'second_column',
        logx=True)


    # LOG XAXIS
    if logaxis = 'x':

        # establish plot
        data.plot.scatter(
            'first_column',
            'second_column',
            logx=True
        )

        # axis range controls
        x_interval = interval

        # x axis (ie x-axis variable)
        x_buffer = (data.first_column.max() - data.first_column.min()) / x_interval

        plt.axis(
            xmin=1,                                      # use for xaxis lower buffer if logx and close to 0
            xmax=data.first_column.max()+x_buffer,       # sets xaxis upper buffer
            #xmin=data.first_column.min()-x_buffer,      # sets xaxis lower buffer if not logx close to 0
        )


    # LOG YAXIS
    if logaxis = 'y':

        # establish plot
        data.plot.scatter(
            'first_column',
            'second_column',
            logy=True
        )

        # axis range controls
        y_interval = interval

        # x axis (ie x-axis variable)
        y_buffer = (data.second_column.max() - data.second_column.min()) / y_interval

        plt.axis(
            ymin=1,                                       # use for yaxis lower buffer if logy and close to 0
            ymax=data.second_column.max()+y_buffer,       # sets yaxis upper buffer
            #ymin=data.second_column.min()-y_buffer,      # sets yaxis lower buffer if not logy close to 0
        )


    # NOT X OR Y PASSED
    if (logaxis != 'x') & (logaxis != 'y'):

        # establish plot
        data.plot.scatter(
            'first_column',
            'second_column')
```